# How to hide all posts from timeline in Facebook

Tags: facebook, privacy

Is there any way to remove all of my previous post from my Facebook timeline? Or remove all activities from a Facebook app with a single click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no first-party way to *delete* it, but you can set it so that only you can view it.

Head to **Privacy Settings** and edit the "*Who can see my stuff?*" setting so that only you can.

[image: Who can see my stuff?]

Next, use the "*Limit The Audience for Old Posts on Your Timeline*" tool to retroactively change the privacy setting for *every* previous post on your timeline.

[image: Limit the audience for old posts on your timeline]

From now on, only you will see anything that would normally appear on your own timeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to rid your Facebook profile of all content, I would recommend the [Web 2.0 Suicide Machine](http://suicidemachine.org/) created by [Danja Vasiliev](http://k0a1a.net/).